# How to connect to remote MySQL database in node JavaScript (using PHP configuration file)

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Suppose my website is: https://www.anysite.com and the path for configuration file is: https://www.anysite.com:/include my adminconnction.php file on the host is:

```
<?php
    $host_name='db0000000.hosting-data';
    $database='db';
    $user_name='user';
    $password='password';
    $link =new mysqli($host_name,$user_name,$password,$database);
    if ($link->connect_error){
        die();
        return;
    }
?>
```

In node JavaScript I try to connect MySQL on localhost it work but when I connect to my host it failed. Here is some of my code. app.js

```
 const express  = require("express"),
 bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
 http        =require('http'),
 url         =require('url'),
 mysql       = require("mysql"),
 path        = require("path"),
 app         = express(),
 port        = 8081;
 
 app.set("port", process.env.port || port);
 console.log("main path="+ __dirname);
 app.set("views",__dirname+"/views");
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

 const db = mysql.createConnection({
     host : "db0000000.hosting-data",
     user : "user",
     password : "password",
     database : "db"
     });

 db.connect((err)=>{
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log('connection complete successfully');
 });


 app.listen(port,()=>{
     console.log("server running on port:"+ port);
 });
```

When I run nodemon I get error

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db0000000.hosting-data db0000000.hosting-data:3306 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)

Comment: Anybody help with that please

Comment: Hei want help please

Comment: What happens when you connect directly to the DB instance using the same parameters from via Terminal, phpMyAdmin, or a MySQL GUI tool - does it succeed? What query have you not included in your example code which is being executed and triggering the thrown error? Is your DBinstance located behind any security solutions such as a firewall or Security Group (AWS)?